# Make Ubuntu only start if an USB flash drive is connected

Tags: 12.04, usb, login

This may sound weird, but I got this idea and I would love to put it in practice. I have an USB flash drive that I carry with me everytime, and I would like to create a system to make my Ubuntu only start IF that flash USB is connected, just like a key that turns on a car (the login screen should appear only if the "key" is connected - I would have to put my password too). This will be a great improvement on my computer's system (and would also be kind of fun).

It would be also nice to have more than one "key", in case a flash drive gets broken...

So, the question is, is this possible? If yes, how can I make it?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I have seen this somewhere before. So I can assure you that this is possible.
I can't exactly remember how it was done. Though I think it was something like it only displayed Ubuntu on Grub if your USB was installed, or something along those lines.

Comment: It would be awesome to have something like this... Hope someone come up with a solution! :D

Answer (score 1):

I did a thorough Google search and can't find the solution that I had saw months back, I apologise, but I did find something similar that may or may not work. I admit, that I don't know too much about Grub or whether or not you can use this for your purposes, but it does seem likely to work.

[This link takes you to a page that describes how to create a GRUB Rescue USB](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2009/08/grub-on-bootable-usb-rescue-stick.html)

It is basically designed just for a situation that your Grub breaks. However, if I am correct, if you somehow manage to delete the Ubuntu entry from your pre-existing grub after creating it (assuming you Dual-boot) then starting up your PC will not show Ubuntu, unless you plug in your new USB that will boot-up the Grub that displays your Ubuntu install.

I know that this is risky, so I would recommend you wait till someone clarifies whether my idea works or not. If no one replies, then go ahead and ask on an Ubuntu forum.

Good luck, and I hope I haven't inconvenienced you with this idea. I'm not too knowledgeable when it comes to Grub.

Comment: Do you think it would be "possible" to test this under VirtualBox? That way I could try everything without fear of breaking something.

Comment: I would guess that it's a good possibility of working under VB. Give it a try, but I would recommend you take the idea to people on forums. That way you wouldn't need to waste time on something that may not even work.

Comment: @nirpius reported the desired behavior as a problem, on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1534248 the answer may give you a hint.